# Electron app stops rendering while running Javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm currently working on an electron app that is essentially a DDNS launcher for a media server I control. Basically, it checks for an internet connection, gets the current IP for the server, then opens it in the system's default browser. However, the splash screen that I wrote is totally broken.

Whenever I launch the app on my system (using npm from the terminal), it loads the frame, but the image freezes loading at about the 1/3 point. It won't load the rest of the image until the script that it at the bottom of the main HTML page is finished executing.

Is there something I'm missing about this? I can provide excerpts of the code if needed.

## EDIT:

Source code excerpt:

```js
<script>
  function wait(ms) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while (end < start + ms) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
    }
  }

const isOnline = require('is-online');
const isReachable = require('is-reachable');
const {
  shell
} = require('electron');

window.onload = function() {
  // Main Script
  console.log('before');
  wait(3000);
  document.getElementById('progresstext').innerHTML = "Testing connection...";
  bar.animate(0.15); // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
  wait(250);
  var amIOnline = false;

  if (isOnline()) {
    amIOnline = true;
  }
  console.log("Internet Test Ran");

  if (!amIOnline) {
    document.getElementById('errortext').innerHTML = "ERROR: No internet connection. Check the internet connection.";
    document.getElementById('progresstext').innerHTML = "ERROR";
  }

  var isEmbyReachable = false;
  if (isReachable('******')) {
    isEmbyReachable = true;
    document.getElementById('progresstext').innerHTML = "Connection Test: Passed";
    //=> true
  }

  //Open Emby in the default browser
  if (amIOnline && isEmbyReachable) {
    shell.openExternal("*****");
  }
};

</script>
```

Pastebin link to the full source: https://pastebin.com/u1iZeSSK

Thanks

Development System Specs: macOS Mojave 10.14, Latest stable build of electron

Comment: may be mix use 'onload' with 'DOMContentLoaded'? 
can you show some code ?

Comment: Please post the code, that blocks the rendering

Comment: Just updated the post, but here's another link to the pastebin for the code: https://pastebin.com/u1iZeSSK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `wait` function, since node js is sigle threaded your wait function is blocking your process. You may try following code. But I really recommend you to take a look at how to write async functions in JavaScript and setInterval and setTimeout as a start.

But for the time you may try this code.

```
window.onload = function () {
    // Main Script
    console.log('before');

    // wait 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('progresstext').innerHTML = "Testing connection...";
        bar.animate(0.15); // Number from 0.0 to 1.0

        // wait 250 mills
        setTimeout(function () {
            var amIOnline = false;

            if (isOnline()) {
                amIOnline = true;
            }
            console.log("Internet Test Ran");

            if (!amIOnline) {
                document.getElementById('errortext').innerHTML = "ERROR: No internet connection. Check the internet connection.";
                document.getElementById('progresstext').innerHTML = "ERROR";
            }

            var isEmbyReachable = false;
            if (isReachable('******')) {
                isEmbyReachable = true;
                document.getElementById('progresstext').innerHTML = "Connection Test: Passed";
                //=> true
            }

            //Open Emby in the default browser
            if (amIOnline && isEmbyReachable) {
                shell.openExternal("*****");
            }
        }, 250)
    }, 3000)


};
```

You may not while or any other blocking loops to wait in JavaScript since it will block all other executions including page rendering.

Comment: Gotcha. that would do it. Thanks for the little lesson in setTimeout. :D